# How do I search a page using a regular expression in Firefox?

Tags: firefox

I want to use regular expressions to search a page in Firefox.

Is this possible?

Comment: Please change your accepted answer. The one you picked years ago is about an extension that isn't being developed anymore.

Comment: See also these similar questions: [How can I search for regular expressions within webpages using Google Chrome or IE?](https://superuser.com/q/417875) and [How to run a regex search on Google Chrome or Firefox?](https://superuser.com/q/385418)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

<s>[Fastest Search](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/fastest-search)</s> [no longer available]

> Best text search on page/in tabs -
> count/regex/match distribution/list/find-as-you-type.
> Fastest Instant web/history search in URLBar.
> Best custom search and multi-tab preview in any
> box or for selected text. Autocopy, dnd link/image.

Comment: I won't put -1, but to me, this addon is too much bloated...

Comment: Couldn't make it work on Mac

Comment: No longer compatible.

Comment: Not available anymore

Answer (score 41):

Since the other alternatives offered here have been left in the dust of technological change, and rendered incompatible with latest versions, I'll drop the two current compatible addons I found (though I haven't tested them):

- [**Regex Search**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/regexsearch/)
  Search in HTML or Highlight using Regular Expression (REGEX) and output the results using template, with saving profiles functionality, you need to know 'basic' Regular expression to benefit from this plugin
- [**{find+}**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/brandon1024-find/)
  {find+} is a simple Find-in-Page extension hosting a the ability to search a web page or document by regular expression. It has been designed to look and behave much like the CTRL-F function, but extended to provide a feature-rich and robust user experience with the aim of completely replacing the native Find-in-Page tool.

Comment: Neither "Regex Search" nor "{find+}" give results for `\p{IsCyrillic}` on page full of text in Russian.

Comment: Upvote only for {find}+ since it acts as find but regex search doesnt highlight in the page.

Comment: @Mark To clarify your comment, [{find}+](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/brandon1024-find/) *does* highlight regex search result in the page. The alternative extension [Regex Search](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/regexsearch/) may not – which is what you say.

Comment: @Mark Regex Search does highlight on the page

Answer (score 12):

Yet another option matching my needs very well is <s>[Regex Find](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/regex-find/)</s> (no long available on Firefox marketplace) [which is open sourced](https://github.com/mortalis13/Regex-Find). It's simple, though it may not be so polished.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I honestly prefer this way more to @Oleg's answer of Fastest Search. IMO it's super bloated and kinda confusing, I love the fact that Regex Find is integrated into the native Firefox search

Comment: Does currently not work with Firefox 50: https://github.com/mortalis13/Regex-Find/issues/6

Comment: @tlo: some instructions in the about field on [how to run it on current versions](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/regex-find/), if you like to live adverturously.

Comment: Not available anymore

Comment: The page doesn't exist anymore!

Answer (score 4):

<s>[XUL/Migemo](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5239/)</s> (no long available)

> This includes 3 features about the
> find toolbar. First, the
> dictionary-assisted find. Second, more
> customizable Find Toolbar. Third, the
> highlight feature like Safari 3.

Comment: Not available for FF6 yet ...

Comment: @Peter Nore: You can try to turn off the compatibility checking. I am still using add-ons from FF4 that are supposedly not compatible, and most of them work just fine.

Comment: How do you activate the regex search functionality with XUL/Migemo?

Comment: It seems development on this plugin has stopped. The last updated date on the addon page is `July 13, 2010`.

Comment: yeah shame, not available for latest versions of Firefox! any alternatives?

Comment: @Charbel: There is a good chance that XUL/Migemo can still be forced to work. A quick google for "firefox add-on compatibility" got me [this article](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-make-any-firefox-add-on-compatible-with-all-versions/), but there are many more useful results.