# Custom search for format or pattern on a web page?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, firefox-extensions

Is there a browser extension which will allow me to perform a search for text with a specific format on a web page?

For example: [3 digits]-[3 digits]-[4 digits] (for a phone number)

Or: 10 digits (for a phone number)

Or: [2 digits]/[2 digits]/[2 digits] (for a date)

Or other custom patterns?

Any major browser is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), it's fairly simple to install one of the extensions that Dennis pointed out on [this](https://superuser.com/a/385422/23420) question.

Of the two extensions, I'd recommend [Regular Expression Search](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/regular-expression-search/haocppnjhmfiemhgfdgockbipphbfibe) because its interface is a bit more obvious.

So your examples, in regex:

**Phone Number**: `\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}` or `\d{10}`
**Date**: `\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}`

Comment: Thank you! It's good to know that this can be done with regular expressions. However, it seems that [Regular Expression Search](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/regular-expression-search/haocppnjhmfiemhgfdgockbipphbfibe) doesn't let you navigate through the search results :( Quite weak. Or am I not seeing something?