# How can I search for regular expressions within webpages using Google Chrome or IE?

Tags: google-chrome, regex

How can I search for regular expressions like 'foo|bar' on webpages using Google Chrome or IE? I'm aware of the "Regular Expression Searcher" extension, but it does not work for me. (Nothing happens when I hit slash.) The reviews on the web store indicate that this is a common problem for many users.

Comment: You don't use Firefox, but you might find one of its add-ons interesting: deeper web http://deeperweb.com/  It doesn't do REs, but it does assist finer grained searching.  If you're really desperate, you could always save the source of a web page and then search it with a utility or editor that does support REs, but that would be pretty ugly.

Comment: maybe use NotePad++ as external editor for web pages. There you can search for regexps.

Comment: See also these similar (but not identical!) questions: [How do I search a page using a regular expression in Firefox?](https://superuser.com/q/208652) and [How do I search a page using a regular expression in Firefox?](https://superuser.com/q/208652)

Answer (score 57):

### Using Javascript to match regular expressions

Maybe you want try this at chrome's console:

```
var p=/.*(regu).+?\ /gi; console.log( document.body.innerText.match(p) );
```

Just [open console](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools#access), copy and paste above to console and hit <kbd>enter</kbd>. You can test it here at this page.
This can be improved if it fits in.

Here we print to console match indexes and matched text. Here we try to match text that contains `regu`, 20 chars before (or less if start of line) and 10 chars after (or less if eol).

```
var p=/.{0,20}regu[^ \n]+[^\n]{0,10}/gi;
while (m = p.exec(document.body.innerText)) { 
    console.log( 'Index: '+m.index+' Match: '+m ); }
```

Also try this, it will **paint background** of all matches on page **red**, rexexp is not perfect but at least it *should* not mess with HTML tags:

```
var p=/(\>{1}[^\n\<]*?)([^\n\<]{0,30}regu[^\n\<]{0,10})/gi,b=document.body;
b.innerHTML=b.innerHTML.replace(p,'$1<span style="background-color:red;">$2</span>');
```

#### Bookmarking this:

Another way to use this is through `javascript:` protocol (same code as just above):

```
javascript:(function(){var p=/(\>{1}[^\n\<]*?)([^\n\<]{0,30}regu[^\n\<]{0,10})/gi,b=document.body;b.innerHTML=b.innerHTML.replace(p,'$1<span style="background-color:red;">$2</span>');})();
```

For example, using `javascript:` protocol one can insert a little search box to any web page for searching regexp's.
I think that you already know that simple regexp can also used to remove red *matches* from page.
If I continue to develop this for few more hours we may have search plugin that fit in bookmark :)

Comment: Some previous versions of chrome do not support `innerText`. It is recommended to check if `innerText` is supported and default to `textContent` if `innerText` is not usable.

Comment: Your initial code for finding elements can be with code `[...document.body.innerText.matchAll(p)]` for 73+ version of Chrome.

Answer (score 11):

The Find+ extension has good reviews and has not been mentioned yet: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/find%20-regex-find-in-page/fddffkdncgkkdjobemgbpojjeffmmofb?hl=en-US

I tried it out, and it works very well and has a clear, simple UI.

It can search text across HTML elements. The others that I tried were unable to do that.

[image]

Comment: I pushed enter it didn't highlight a thing

Comment: @barlop - Make sure you're using the actual extension's finder. It doesn't replace the Chrome's native finder.

Comment: @AndrewCheong https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEKqn.png

Comment: Oh, it doesn't work for me on the extension page either. But it works for me on regular sites.

Comment: +1 At this time this is also the only one with a statement on privacy practices.

Comment: @barlop, I think maybe the search won't work on pages that are open before you install the add-on. You have to reload them.

Answer (score 5):

[Regular Expression Search](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/haocppnjhmfiemhgfdgockbipphbfibe) from Google Chrome.

> A simple search utility that allows you to search a web page using
> regular expression.
>
> Features under development
>
> - toggle through found results
> - improved UI
> - toggle between case sensitivity
> - create shortcut for toggling the extension
> - Allow pressing "Enter" key when searching (instead of clicking on search button)
>
> **Important Notes**
> This is a page action extension so it won't work right away on the  page you have already opened. I recommend restart your browser before start using this extension. You can also try to refresh your opened page.

Comment: I don't have a better suggestion, but this extension doesn't work very well. While enabled, AdBlock doesn't block all ads. Also, after searching this page, for example, the *add comment* stops working.

Comment: The link appears unavailable. Is it the same extension as [Chrome Regex Search](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-regex-search/bpelaihoicobbkgmhcbikncnpacdbknn)?

Answer (score 4):

I would like to suggest the [Chrome Regex Search](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-regex-search/bpelaihoicobbkgmhcbikncnpacdbknn) extension.

[This extension is open source](https://github.com/rogershen/chrome-regex-search).

Comment: I think you are suggesting this as a solution, so I edited it. Also you can provide a link without displaying the full link. You click on the chain link icon which is visible when you are typing your answer.

Answer (score 3):

The other extensions that were mentioned didn't work for me, so I wrote my own open source chrome extension that you can try out here: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/regex-search/bcdabfmndggphffkchfdcekcokmbnkjl?hl=en&gl=US

Source code is available on github: https://github.com/gsingh93/regex-search

Answer (score 2):

In Chrome on macOS, hold <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to open Developer Tools, select the HTML source code for the page (under the "Sources" tab), hold <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to search, and select the `.*` (Regex) symbol.

If you need to search only text, you can use [pandoc](https://pandoc.org/) to convert HTML to plain text:

```
$ pandoc https://superuser.com/questions/417875 -t plain -o tmp.txt
```

And then use `less` to search with Regex (search with `/`).

Answer (score 1):

In Chrome Developer Tools mode, type <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> (on Windows, not sure about other OS).

There's a reg-ex option for searching. This will search all files, so it will include JavaScript source. I'm not sure (how) you can limit it to only HTML.

Answer (score 0):

not really a search, but I found this regexp highlighter (that I found somewhere) quite useful, and works for all browsers.

```
javascript:(function(){var%20count=0,%20text,%20regexp;text=prompt(%22Search%20regexp:%22,%20%22%22);if(text==null%20||%20text.length==0)return;try{regexp=new%20RegExp(%22(%22%20+%20text%20+%22)%22,%20%22i%22);}catch(er){alert(%22Unable%20to%20create%20regular%20expression%20using%20text%20'%22+text+%22'.\n\n%22+er);return;}function%20searchWithinNode(node,%20re){var%20pos,%20skip,%20spannode,%20middlebit,%20endbit,%20middleclone;skip=0;if(%20node.nodeType==3%20){pos=node.data.search(re);if(pos%3E=0){spannode=document.createElement(%22SPAN%22);spannode.style.backgroundColor=%22yellow%22;middlebit=node.splitText(pos);endbit=middlebit.splitText(RegExp.$1.length);middleclone=middlebit.cloneNode(true);spannode.appendChild(middleclone);middlebit.parentNode.replaceChild(spannode,middlebit);++count;skip=1;}}else%20if(%20node.nodeType==1%20&&%20node.childNodes%20&&%20node.tagName.toUpperCase()!=%22SCRIPT%22%20&&%20node.tagName.toUpperCase!=%22STYLE%22){for%20(var%20child=0;%20child%20%3C%20node.childNodes.length;%20++child){child=child+searchWithinNode(node.childNodes[child],%20re);}}return%20skip;}window.status=%22Searching%20for%20%22+regexp+%22...%22;searchWithinNode(document.body,%20regexp);window.status=%22Found%20%22+count+%22%20match%22+(count==1?%22%22:%22es%22)+%22%20for%20%22+regexp+%22.%22;})();
```

Comment: All the UUencoded chars makes it hard to read, I found what appears to be the multiline version at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280195/differences-between-two-regex-javascript-bookmarklets

Comment: I use the regexp highlighter from this site and it works fairly well for me http://dpatrickcaldwell.blogspot.in/2010/09/regular-expression-search-bookmarklet.html

Comment: I needed the normal (not bookmarklet) JS (for use in Chrome extension), and solution from @buffer link worked fine

Comment: I should have scrolled down before I did it myself... https://pastebin.com/VA9xvmM8