# How can I search with the `OR` operator in Chrome web browser?

Tags: google-chrome, search, find

Using Chrome's find on page function  <kbd>CTRL+F</kbd> , how can I search with the `OR` operator? i.e. search for `aaa` or `bbb` within the webpage that Chrome shows?

[image]

btw , I prefer not to use Extension or plugin

Comment: I think maybe chrome and perhaps other brownsers haven't developed that that well.. there may be an answer with extensions to chrome https://superuser.com/questions/417875/how-can-i-search-for-regular-expressions-within-webpages-using-google-chrome-or    BTW in regex, OR would be | or ||

Comment: I think it's not possible because writing OR interprets it as text as well and not logical operator.

Comment: I am not certain Chrome supports this natively, but a Chrome plugin like [efTwo (F2) - Advanced Find on Page](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/eftwo-f2-advanced-find-on/ccaikggmppdolhcehimngikgiafmdcep) might be worth a look.

Answer (score 0):

Natively, this is not support (and I doubt it ever will be). However, there are certain extensions for that. Some are advanced Find on Page tools, as mentioned, but in general, look for a Regex search tool, e.g. [1](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-regex-search/bpelaihoicobbkgmhcbikncnpacdbknn/related). These can search for alternates using the `|` symbol, e.g. `aaa|bbb` among many other [regex patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info).

Answer (score 0):

Keyboard workaround: Ctrl+F5, type search word, enter. Press Esc key, then rinse-repeatn for second OR search: Ctrl+F5, type search word, enter