# How do I search a page using a regular expression in Firefox (Quantum versions)?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

Many years ago we had a quesion [How do I search a page using a regular expression in Firefox?](https://superuser.com/q/208652/245275) with several answers.  None of the suggested extentsion are compatible with recent ("Quantum") versions of Firefox, so once again:

*How do I search a page in Firefox using regular expressions?*

Comment: The [regexserach](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/regexsearch/?src=search) extension highlights and can check whether text is on the page but doesn't appear to be capable of scrolling to the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How do I search a page in Firefox Quantum using regular expressions?

You can use [{find+}](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/brandon1024-find/):

> {find+} is a simple Find-in-Page extension hosting a the ability to
> search a web page or document by regular expression. It has been
> designed to look and behave much like the CTRL-F function, but
> extended to provide a feature-rich and robust user experience with the
> aim of completely replacing the native Find-in-Page tool.
>
> Our principle is simple, to deliver a reliable, robust, repeatable,
> performant, and native-like tool for the software and web development
> industry. Perfection is simply not good enough.
>
> Looking for more information? Check out our awesome Wiki by clicking
> the link to our website below.
>
> A Small Notice:
>
> Since {find+} is still in beta, you may experience
> bugs or issues while using the extension. We are hard at work fixing
> these issues, but we encourage you to continue using our extension in
> the meantime. You can keep an eye on current issues in progress by
> monitoring our GitHub page.
>
> [image]

Source [{find+}](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/brandon1024-find/)

Comment: Very nice, now if  only I could map it to `ctrl+F`...  A note for anyone like me testing and thinking it doesn't work: it only works on pages loaded after you installed it (not really surprising in hindsight)